# firefox for android not showing css utf8-symbols

Tags: android, css, firefox, utf-8

I use utf8 characters / symbols from [utf8icons.com](http://www.utf8icons.com/) on my website. The symbol below is not displayed in firefox (34.0) on android even though I chose `unicode` in the firefox menu. I only get a grey square.

On the desktop version of firefox and chromium, it is correctly shown:

◔

```
.timedark:before {
    content: '\25D4';
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #222;
}
```

What could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The font being used does not contain a glyph for the character and neither does any of the fallback fonts that the browser tries to use. The cause may well be that none of the fonts in the system contains this character. The options are the use of a downloadable font via `@font-face` and the use of an image instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use 'PT Serif' from google fonts. The font shows the symbol in desktop browsers. The editor geany is also showing the scss and css files as utf-8 encoded

Comment: @hnes, PT Serif does not contain this character, see http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Serif so you must be seeing it in some other font.